# AS 400 Performance from .Net iSeries Provider

Tags: asp.net, performance, ibm-midrange

First off, I am not an AS 400 guy - at all.  So please forgive me for asking any noobish questions here.

Basically, I am working on a .Net application that needs to access the AS400 for some real-time data.  Although I have the system working, I am getting very different performance results between queries.  Typically, when I make the 1st request against a SPROC on the AS400, I am seeing ~ 14 seconds to get the full data set.  After that initial call, any subsequent calls usually only take ~ 1 second to return.  This performance improvement remains for ~ 20 mins or so before it takes 14 seconds again.

The interesting part with this is that, if the stored procedure is executed directly on the iSeries Navigator, it always returns within milliseconds (no change in response time).

I wonder if it is a caching / execution plan issue but I can only apply my SQL SERVER logic to the AS400, which is not always a match.

Any suggestions on what I can do to recieve a more consistant response time or simply insight as to why the AS400 is acting in this manner when I was using the iSeries Data Provider for .Net?  Is there a better access method that I should use?

Just in case, here's the code I am using to connect to the AS400

```
     Dim Conn As New IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection(ConnectionString)
  Dim Cmd As New IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command("SPROC_NAME_HERE", Conn)
  Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

  Using Conn
   Conn.Open()

   Dim Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
   Using Reader
    While Reader.Read()

               'Do Something

    End While
    Reader.Close()
   End Using

   Conn.Close()
  End Using
```

EDIT:  after looking about a bit on this issue and using some of the comments below, I am beginning to wonder if I am experiencing this due to the gains from connection pooling?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the Redbook [Integrating DB2 Universal Database for iSeries with Microsoft ADO .NET](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html) useful for diagnosing issues like these.

Specifically look into the client and server side traces to help isolate the issue.  And don't be afraid to call IBM software support.  They can help you set up profiling to figure out the issue.

Comment: Wow, this redbook is awesome.  Reading through this now...  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I hope it helps.  Please report back what you discover so that we all benefit from your research.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try a different driver to connect to the AS400-DB2 system. I have used 2 options.

1. the standard jt400.jar driver to create a simple java web service to get my data
2. the drivers from the company called HIT software (www.hitsw.com)

Obviously the first option would be the slower of the two, but thats the free way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Each connection to the iSeries is backed by a job. Upon the first connection, the iSeries driver needs to create the connection pool, start a job, and associate that job with the connection object. When you close a connection, the driver will return that object to the connection pool, but will not end the job on the server.

You can turn on tracing to determine what is happening on your first connection attempt. To do so, add "Trace=StartDebug" to your connection string, and enable trace logging on the box that is running your code. You can do this by using the 'cwbmptrc' tool in the Client Access program directory:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access>cwbmptrc.exe +a
>
> Error logging is on
>   Tracing is on
>
> Error log file name is:
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\iDB2Log.txt
>
> Trace file name is:
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\iDB2Trace.txt

The trace output will give you insight into what operations the driver is performing and how long each operation takes to complete. Just don't forget to turn tracing off once you are done (cwbmptrc.exe -a)

If you don't want to mess with the tracing, a quick test to determine if connection pooling is behind the delay is to disable it by adding "Pooling=false" to your connection string. If connection pooling the is reason that your 2nd attempt is much faster, disabling connection pooling *should* make each request perform as slowly as the first.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar performance from iSeries SQL (ODBC) queries for several years.   I think it's part of the nature of the beast-- OS/400 dynamically moves data from disk to memory when it's accessed.

FWIW, I've also noticed that the iSeries is more like a tractor than a race car.  It deals much better with big loads.   In one case, I consolidated about a dozen short queries into a single monstrous one, and reduced the execution time from something like 20 seconds to about 2 seconds.

Comment: Your Tractor / Racecar analogy is perfect!  I feel like I am trying to turn a John Deere into a race car.  I will try batching information together to see how it compares to the cumlative time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had to pull data from the AS/400 in the past, basically there were a couple of things that worked for me:

1) Dump data into a SQL Server table nightly where I could control the indexes, the native SqlClient beats the IBM DB2 .NET Client every time
2) Talk to one of your AS400 programmers and make sure the command you are using is hitting a **logical** file as opposed to a physical (logical v/s physical in their world is akin to our tables v/s views)
3) Create Views using a Linked Server on SQL server and query your views.

Comment: Originally, we went w/ the nightly integration, but the data in this case HAS to be real-time.  I built a killer of a caching engine for this, but even a 2 min old cache was too old for the users.  :(

Comment: As for the logical file, we have SPROCs built on the AS400 that are hitting the table.  Should the items queried inside the SPROC be hitting logicals instead?

Comment: Great suggestion on the linked server.  We had to move away from that due to the fact that we are not running Enterprise Server, nor are we able to acquire software like Hit to manage that for us.  Great points, all around.

Comment: I think hitting the logicals might help, they always helped me, also, I had one instance where I had a logical with the same key throughout the file, i.e. there was a column whose value was always =1, e.g. DMREG was always 1. The AS400 programmer said, even if that column is always 1, pass it in your query, since its a "key" field, it will help performance, I didn't delve into why, but it did... :D

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what the licensing requirements are for linked server, we didn't manage them per se from Ent. Mgr, we just created views via queries on logicals...

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the same behavior when connecting to Iseries data from Java solutions hosted on Websphere Application Server (WAS) as well as .Net solutions hosted on IIS. The first call of the day is always more "expensive" than the second.
The delay on the first call is caused by the "setup" time for the Iseries to set up the job to service the request, (job name is QZDASOINIT in subsystem QUSRWRK). Subsequent calls will reuse the existing jobs that stay active waiting for more incoming requests.
The number of QZDASOINIT jobs and how long they stay active is configurable on the Iseries.
One document on how to tune your prestart job entries: 
http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/tipstechniques/systemsmanagement/Tuning-Prestart-Job-Entries/ 
I guess it would be a reasonable assumption that there is also some overhead to the "first call of the day" on both WAS and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a stored procedure.  This will create and cache your access plan with the stored procedure, so optimizer doesn't have to look in the SQL cache or reoptimize.